# How can I output the count of a specific taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, woocommerce

I am trying to output the count of product categories that have been created for the custom post type product_cat.

When I use:

```
<?php
$count_posts = wp_count_posts('product_cat');
echo $count_posts->publish; 
?>
```

it outputs "0" although there have been 3 categories created. I have searched through all of he plugin files to see how the count is output on the edit product categories page in the Wordpress admin interface. I normally refrain from asking questions due to the fact that I am new and self taught so forgive me if my terminology is not 100% correct.

Comment: I'd suggest posting your solution as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Leon, posting your solution as an answer helps get this question out of the unanswered lists

Comment: Got it, thanks I am new here or was really new in september. Sorry now I know.

Answer (score 0):

Use [wp_count_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_terms):

```
<?php
    $product_cat_count = wp_count_terms( 'product_cat' );
    echo $product_cat_count; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks hitautodestruct! oops.